# How to print huge number of items from the json array

Tags: javascript, json

This is my json format with that im displaying my array items like this.

If i have more items in my array mean how can i print that all using for loop or is there any method available to print all that items in an array?

```js
{
"workers": [
            { "id": "5001", "type": "Basic" },
            { "id": "5002", "type": "Admin" },
            { "id": "5003", "type": "Basic" }
        ],
        

"clients": [
            { "id": "5004", "type": "Pro" },
            { "id": "5005", "type": "Basic" },
            { "id": "5006", "type": "Basic" },
            { "id": "5007", "type": "Pro" }
        ]
}
```

```js
<script>
    const api_url = "API URL";

    async function get_data_from_api() {
        const response = await fetch(api_url);
        var data = await response.json();

        var track = data["workers"][2]["id"];
        document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML = track ;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `echo`? `json_decode` ? ... this is PHP not JavaScript

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Comment: sorry wrong code updated the correct one

Comment: anybody help pls

Answer (score 0):

Reference:

[JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#select-language)

```js
const o = {
"workers": [
            { "id": "5001", "type": "Basic" },
            { "id": "5002", "type": "Admin" },
            { "id": "5003", "type": "Basic" }
        ],
        

"clients": [
            { "id": "5004", "type": "Pro" },
            { "id": "5005", "type": "Basic" },
            { "id": "5006", "type": "Basic" },
            { "id": "5007", "type": "Pro" }
        ]
};
output.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(o, undefined, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```